# Apollo Client React and local state best practices

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client

I am working on my first GraphQL React Client app and I am not sure about some best practices.

I have a query, that gets me places from an API to be shown on a map.
In the `map.js` component I fetch the data with this query:

```
const GET_PLACES_ON_MAP = gql`
  query Region($input: MapInput!) {
    map(input: $input) {
      places {
        id
        name
        distance
        long
        lat
      }
      infos {
        totalPlacesInArea
        responseTime
      }
    }
  }
`;

const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_PLACES_ON_MAP, someQueryParams);
```

The response includes `infos` about the total number of places and the response time of API response.
This `infos` object should be used in other components too (e.g. in some kind of dashboard) and it changes everytime a new query is made in the map component.

My **question no 1**:

What's the best practice to use `infos` in another component that do not query the API itselves?

My first try was to save `infos` in a local state graphql object like with the following mutation and resolver code (this sets the infos in local state but I get endless rendering of the map component):

```
const SET_API_INFO = gql`
  mutation {
    setApiInfo(params: $params) @client
  }
`;

const GET_API_INFO = gql`
  {
    apiInfo @client {
      totalPlacesInArea
      responseTime
    }
  }
`;

const resolvers = {
  Mutation: {
    setApiInfo: (_root, variables, { cache, getCacheKey }) => {
      const { apiInfo } = cache.readQuery({ query: GET_API_INFO });
      const { params } = variables;
      _.map(params, (value, key) => {
        apiInfo[key] = value;
      });
      cache.writeData({ data: { apiInfo } });
    },
  },
};
```

My **question no 2**:

I was looking for some tutorial or an open source project that uses Apollo Client & React to learn more about the architecture of a really complex app. Is there anywhere a good example that goes further then *query, mutation, subscription*?

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need to store your data in the client cache because Apollo supports `fetchPolicy`. When you use the same query with the same variables, query fields in any component, Apollo will look up its cache query first before making a new network request. If the query has existed, Apollo will return the last query result.

> By default, Apollo Client's fetch policy is cache-first, which means it checks the cache to see if the result is there before making a network request. Since we want this list to always reflect the newest data from our graph API, we set the `fetchPolicy` for this query to network-only.

2. I don't know any Apollo complex app, but you can read more about Apollo's best practices in [Apollo blog](https://www.apollographql.com/blog/introducing-the-apollo-client-best-practices-series/).